# Mongoose ignores $ne while updating document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, socket.io

I'm building a persistent html fields framework using Node, Mongoose, and Socket.io for the backend. I've run into what seems like a bug in Mongoose's update method.

The documents in mongo look like this:

```
{
    "_id" : "pickable_qty",
    "currently_connected" : [ ],
    "locks" : [
        {
            socket_id: 'eQYVyz1z28rJZRPpAAAB',
            unique_values:{
                merchant_warehouse_id: 11.1,
                product_item_id: 5555
            }
        },
        {
            socket_id: 'eQYVyz1z28rJZRPpAAAB',
            unique_values:{
                merchant_warehouse_id: 11.2,
                product_item_id: 5555
            }
        },
        {
            socket_id: 'eQYVyz1z28rJZRPpAAAB',
            unique_values:{
                merchant_warehouse_id: 11.1,
                product_item_id: 1234
            }
        }
    ],
    "definition" : {
        "ajax_url" : "/persistent-fields/pickable_qty",
        "unique_keys" : [
            "product_item_id",
            "merchant_warehouse_id"
        ],
        "max_idle_seconds" : 30,
        "field_type" : "text"
    },
    "__v" : 0
}
```

The problem arises when I start inserting subdocuments into the `locks` array.

I insert them using Mongoose's `update` method like so:

```
FieldSchema.update(
    {
        _id: 'pickable_qty',
        'locks.unique_values': { 
            '$ne': { 
                merchant_warehouse_id: 11.1, 
                product_item_id: 5334 
            } 
        },
        'definition.unique_keys': { 
            '$all': [ 
                'merchant_warehouse_id', 
                'product_item_id' 
            ] 
        } 
    },
    {
        '$push': {
            locks: { 
                socket_id: 'eQYVyz1z28rJZRPpAAAB', 
                unique_values: {
                    merchant_warehouse_id: 11.1, 
                    product_item_id: 5334 
                } 
            } 
        }
    },
    function(err, count, res){
        console.log('err:', err, 'count:', count, 'res:', res);
        //err: null count: 1 res: { ok: true, n: 1, updatedExisting: true }
    }
);
```

The first insert works exactly as expected, there were no `locks` in the array containing the unique values `{merchant_warehouse_id: 11.1,product_item_id: 5334}` so the document was found and the `lock` subdocument was inserted.

However running this same update the second time should not insert a new `locks` subdocument because one already exists with the same `unique_values` and the `$ne` part of the query should cause it to return no matches to update.

I have confirmed that doing a `find` with the same query returns no documents both on the MongoDB command line and using Mongoose's own `Schema.find` method, but the `Schema.update` method still finds a document and inserts a duplicate `lock` subdoc.

Am I just going crazy or is there a reason why Mongoose's `find` method won't retrieve the document while `update` will?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After using MongoDB's query profiler, I figured out that Mongoose was switching the order of the keys in the `lock`'s `unique_values` object while doing the update query. Then it was inserting the duplicate subdocuments with the keys in the correct order. So apparently MongoDB's `$ne` operator will match nested subdocument arrays only if the keys in the subdocument are in the same order as your query.

Comment: In general, equality testing for subdocuments in MongoDB depends on key order, see [exact match on embedded documents](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#exact-match-on-the-embedded-document) from the MongoDB Manual. It's probably not what one expects. Mongoose should know this and take it into account - I'd consider filing an issue in the Mongoose Github project to see if that behavior is intentional.

Comment: I think the problem is that because I'm using Node and Node is Javascript, the object keys actually [don't have an order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are querying whether or not an object matches a subdocument, and this can be tricky. What you want to do use a combination of $elemMatch and $ne in your query.

```
var query = {
    _id: 'pickable_qty',
    'locks': { 
        $elemMatch: {
            merchant_warehouse_id: {
                $ne: 11.1
            },
            product_item_id: {
                $ne: 5334
            }
        }
    },
    'definition.unique_keys': { 
        '$all': [ 
            'merchant_warehouse_id', 
            'product_item_id' 
        ] 
    } 
}
```

It's basically a query for a document inside of an array.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I can't seem to get that query to retrieve any documents, even with empty `locks` and omitting the `$all`. It just seems strange that the original query works except in the context of Mongoose's `update` method

Comment: @RazVarren Can you try this inside of your mongo shell?

Comment: Yes, I tried it both in the mongo shell and on mongoose's `update` method. I was not able to retrieve any documents with empty `locks` using it.

Comment: What about using locks: {$ne: []} as well?

Comment: using `locks:{$ne:[]}` does match if there is at least one subdocument in the array, but what I am trying to prevent is having duplicate `locks`. I've update the original post to show a list of what I consider unique `locks` in the database. Basically I want to prevent mongoose from inserting a second `locks` subdocument with the same `unique_values` in it. The `"locks.unique_values":{$ne: {merchant_warehouse_id: 11.1, product_item_id: 5334}}` does exactly this in the mongo shell's `find` and `update`. Using mongoose's `find` also works correct but mongoose's `update` seems to ignore the `$ne`

Comment: Unfortunately `$addToSet` for documents, cause that would fix this whole issue. :(